# How do I extend the context deadline?

Tags: chainlink

I am running a job which fetches data from an API. Sometimes the request fails with

`error making http request: Get "http://XXX/0xFA103c21ea2DF71DFb92B0652F8B1D795e51cdEf": context deadline exceeded`

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrGMz.png)

Is there a way I could extend the deadline?
I tried adding `maxTaskDuration` and `timeout`, that doesn't seem to be working either.
This is the part of my job description fetching requests -

```
schemaVersion = 1
name = "score multiple"
contractAddress = "0x502B4BadDe549E5338676bF9caF9C415463A4c74"
maxTaskDuration = "5m0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="http" method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.get)" timeout="300s"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by updating `DEFAULT_HTTP_TIMEOUT` in `.env`

refrence:
https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/configuration#default_http_timeout